# DataTables - Ignore drill down rows with colspan

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using DataTables for a table in my web application. The table lists some data from the database.

I decided to make a drill down where when you click on the row, it will toggle another row below to show more details.

I have this right now.

```
<tr class="main-row">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="drill-down-row">
    <td colspan="3">
        // Drill down content here
    </td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.main-row', function(event){   
    var $line = $(this);
        $line.next('.drill-down-row').toggle();
});
```

After I added the drill down row, DataTables broke because of the new row has only 1 cell. I searched everywhere and can't find a way to ignore the row.

I really need to utilize the django's template renderer and prefer not to use javascript templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatables requires every row in your table to have the same number of cells.

This is what you need to do:

1. Cache all the drill down rows
2. Put the cached row in jQuery's data into `.main-row`
3. Remove all the drill down rows from the table
4. Initialize DataTables
5. Bind `.main-row` on click to insert the cached row from the data after itself.

---

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    // CACHE THEN DELETE ALL DRILL DOWN ROWS !!

    $('.main-row').each(function(){
        var $row = $(this);
        var $rowmore = $row.next('.drill-down-row');

        if($rowmore.length>0){
            $row.data('cached-row', $rowmore);
        }
    });

    $('.drill-down-row').remove();

    // INITIALIZE YOUR DATATABLE HERE !!!!



    $(document).on('click', '.main-row', function(event){   
        var $line = $(this);
        if($line.data('cached-row')){
            $line.data('cached-row').toggle().insertAfter($line);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This was answered quite a while, but i'm trying to use your solution and I'm getting: 

DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown parameter '7' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4 

It seems that datatables have an issue with non-existent rows. If they're not in the HTML on page load, before this script kicks in, it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: @AlexCheuk Do you have any idea about [How to create jQuery Datatable Drill-down rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39991927/how-to-create-jquery-datatable-drill-down-rows) Thanks in advance...